# Flash allocation scheme, bug or feature?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Having the following code:

```
var loadingSoundTitle:String;
var loadingSound:Sound = new Sound();
function loadFile(str:String)
{
    loadingSound = new Sound(); //(1)
    loadingSoundTitle = str;
    try
    {
        loadingSound.load(new URLRequest(loadingSoundTitle));
    }
    catch(err:Error)
    {
        trace(err.message);
    }
}
```

Doesn't work if the line marked with (1) is there, however if I comment out this line, its able to load one single file, before it stops working.

Using ActionScript 3.0 under CS5

Edit: I'm perfectly new to flash!

```
loadingSound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event)
{
    list.addItem({label:loadingSoundTitle, data:loadingSound});
    process.value = 0; //for the nice little processbar I got :)
});
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean - is there a compilation error?  Do you get an error message? Does the file load, but the sound doesn't play? Which is it?

Comment: Ah sorry, thing is, the function runs perfectly, no compilation errors, no error messages, nothing, listening to event yields no effect at all. - The progress, complete and load is never thrown; it simply just doesn't work. - I kinda realized that it had something to do with the allocation, so I found the bug/feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot that's missing here.  I think I see what your problem is though.  Firstly, the AS3 livedocs will tell you that a Sound object instance can load one and only one external mp3, so it's no surprise that removing the line marked with //(1) will work, but only one time.

The other problem I see here is that when you *do* include the line marked with //(1), you're never calling loadingSound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler) or the like.  You *might* be adding it to  your old sound object (if you are, it isn't depicted here), but you're definitely not adding it to your new one.  So with no way for the new sound to report that it's finished loading there's no way to play it after it's done because you never actually know when it's done.

Instead of repeatedly loading the sound over and over, a better way to handle this would be to load the sound one time and then just play it as needed.

EDIT:

Now that I see the listener code, I'm almost positive that's the problem.

1. It's not inside the function call immediately after creating a new sound object.  You have to add a new listener to every new Object instance you create.
2. It's using an anonymous, unbound function.

You'd have to add that function every time you create the new Sound, not just the first time.

Comment: Ok, I got a loadingSound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ..) inplace, its pretty much just handing the loadingSound to a list, the idea is that its loading, and once loaded, its saved in a list, and the same temp var (loadingSound), can be reused, simply be reallocating it with a new sound object, and the loaded sound shouldn't be reallocated by the garbage collector, since its referenced from the list. - Because of what I'm trying to do, its not a possibility to just load files one at a time.

Comment: + I tried loading several into an array, but it didn't work out.

Comment: That's where you're going wrong, then.  A Sound object always and forever will only reference one external mp3.  You *need* to create a new Sound object to load a new mp3.  When you passed that original sound object off to the list, all you're really doing is creating a reference to the object in two places.  So even if you could re-use the same "temp variable" without creating a new Sound object, in this case you'd destructively change the Sounds referenced by the list.  Flash always passes and assigns by reference for any "Object" and always passes and assigns by value for any primitive.

Comment: Well, if what your saying is true, shouldn't the reallocation line (1) make a new Sound object, so that the list one, will be the only one to hold the old sound object? - I mean, I'm loading, then referencing the sound from the list, and the effectively making that the only reference by allocating a new sound to the loadingsound var

Comment: It will, but like I said, I never saw an addEventListener call below that new Sound().  If in fact you really are adding a new listener and it's just not depicted in the sample code, It might be more instructive at this point to clearly state what is going wrong because it seems hazy at this point.

Comment: Updated the OP with my listener

Comment: Updated answer, 'cause the formatting in the comments won't suffice. :)

Comment: Seems likely, will give it a shot, if its correct, I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: Lovely, its working now, I just needed to attach listeners for every single object :) thanks

Comment: No problem!  This is just a nit, and probably isn't going to bite you in this particular instance, but you should remember to call removeEventListener too, as those listeners are going to count as references and can impede garbage collection.  Some people might tell you to set useWeakReference as true, but if you were to do that in this particular case your listener would actually fall out of memory before it could handle the event!  An anonymous function can't be explicitly removed (d'oh!) so you'd need to name the function before you can remove it.

Comment: I did name them :), though that would be more logical in the way the code is structed now; and I'll add some called to removeEventListener :)